# Get file(name) in the dictionary as key and all directories(if file is in) as the value

Tags: python

I have directories and subdirectories, I want to get all the files in the dictionary and also directories into dictionary... Like this:

{'randomfile': '.\map\randomdirectory' , '\map\map2' , \somerandom\map\map3'}

Where key is file(name) and all the directories where this file exsist are in value.

I have my project saved in specific map -> there are also those maps which I want to search for files and folders.., lets say I want to search just the maps where I have saved my project.. How do I do it, .. I know that I do it with recursion but it gets tricky.

And yeah,.. I cant use *os.walk*.

Thanks for potential answer.

Comment: Why can you not use `os.walk`? Is this homework?

Comment: What is tricky about recursion?

Comment: The trick with recursion is, you have to know the recursion trick first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> d = {}
>>> for x,y,z in os.walk('/path/to/dir'):
...   for f in z:
...     if f not in d:
...        d[f] = []
...     d[f].append(x)
...
```

Comment: Well its not the recursion itself, but adding to dictionary. Not sure how do I do it since I always get some strange error.